# Solidify a voronoi object with a defined thickness for 3d printing

Tags: texturing, edit-mode

I would like to 3d print a voronoi rock as a flower pot but I am struggling to  find a way to remove the surface (for placing plants etc) outlined in black in such a way that the object is still a manifold. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with booleans?

Comment: Hmmm… could work… create a cutter object that has a similar contour to the inside walls of the rock?